# Access 2010 subForm editing and adding

Tags: forms, ms-access, edit, subform

I'm trying to do this. My subform is a list of items, each of these items can be rent. So the table structure is something like this:

Mineral
ID | number| ... | Foreign key to location ID

Rent
ID | date_from | date_to | ...

My subform is constitute of a list of minerals and my main, all information about the rent. So when I am updating, it should be something like Update Mineral Set rent = (ID of my main form)

I have try many way to do this with access forms, but I can't find the right parameters.

The viewing is correct, my problem is with the adding et editing functionalities.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are table relationships? Can each rent have multiple minerals? Can each mineral be associated with multiple rent? If yes to both this is a many-to-many relationship. Requires a third (junction) table that associates rent and mineral records. Options for data entry form:

1. single form bound to junction with comboboxes to select rent and mineral
2. main form bound to rent and subform bound to junction with combobox to select mineral
3. main form bound to mineral and subform bound to junction with combobox to select rent

If each rent can have only one mineral then form should be bound to rent with a combobox to select mineral (mineral is the 'lookup' table).

If each mineral can associate with only one rent then form should be bound to mineral with a combobox to select rent (rent is the 'lookup' table).